# Difference Between glob & path Modules

Tags: node.js, module, glob

In `node`, what is the difference between the `glob` and `path` modules? The only differences I could see were that `path` is a built-in module, meaning you don't have to include it as a dependency on your project; both have different functions; and `path` does not need a valid path to work with, but `glob` seems to like one. These differences do not seem to be enough to have both be separate modules, unless perhaps they were created by different people, but in that case, as they are both open-source, it seems like they could be merged.

So, are there any other differences, and why do both exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question:

**Q:** "what is the difference between the glob and path modules?"

**A:** "both have different functions"

`path` is used to manipulate strings that are used in path-related functions.  As such, it's not actually touching the file system (like `fs` does) but it's providing tools to make path manipulation easier.  This saves us from writing the same little bits of code to do this, over and over and over and...

`glob` returns a list of files based upon some directory-and-file path arguments/filters.  It has nothing to do with manipulating path strings.  `path` has nothing to do with reading the file system.

So like you said, "both have different functions."

Comment: So what you are saying is that `glob` gets filenames and `path` performs actions based on possible filenames but doesn't "see" the files themselves?

Comment: Also, does `glob` touch the filesystem itself?

Comment: `path` is just a set of tools for string manipulation.  It is not aware of the file system.  You might feed it two paths or filenames generated from `fs` or other tools, but it's really just about string manipulation.  `glob` generates a list of filenames that you can then use for whatever purposes...a glob like `**/*.js` will return a list of all files ending in `.js` from all subdirectories starting from some root.  `glob` won't change anything; it just gives you a list.